# Cannot perform Skeleton tracking in kinect

Tags: c#, windows, kinect

I'm new to kinect development and was using a skelton tracking example from the book "Beginning Kinect Programming with the Microsoft Kinect SDK". For some reason all the frames that I get in the SkeletonFrameReady event handler are null.

this is how I enable the skeleton stream

```
this._KinectDevice.SkeletonStream.Enable();
this._FrameSkeletons = new Skeleton[this._KinectDevice.SkeletonStream.FrameSkeletonArrayLength];
this._KinectDevice.SkeletonFrameReady += KinectDevice_SkeletonFrameReady;
this._KinectDevice.Start();
```

Here I check for skeleton frame

```
private void KinectDevice_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SkeletonFrame frame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
            { 
             ...//use frame data
            }
        }
```

On debugging I see that the frame returned is always null. 
Can anyone help with what I'm doing incorrectly. The skeleton viewer sample in the SDK works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. The app was workign fine. Just needed to increase the size of the Grid element to accomodate the skeleton